# Enable code coverage indication in Android Studio Gutter

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, user-interface, gutter

When I run my unit tests in the android studio with code coverage and select to see the source from the Coverage toolbar, I cannot see the code coverage information in the gutter(sidebar) of the editor as shown [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2018.1/viewing-code-coverage-results.html). There is no information about the number of hits or color indicators in the gutter.

[image]
[image]

This is what I am using:

Android Studio 3.2.1
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 9, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-34-generic

Answer (score 3):

http://tutorials.webtecho.com/code-coverage-in-android-studio/

Go to configuration -> Unit test , click the drop down then click the project module you would like to enable coverage on then click code coverage and enable tracing . Also click on Analyze then Show code coverage data .

Comment: Switching to "Tracing" in run configuration was it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Run tests with Code coverage
2. Go to that class you write a test for
3. You can see the coverage indication on gutter

Comment: I know I am supposed to get the indication. But my issue is that I am not getting them.